# How to make Background image transparent in iWatch Watchkit

Tags: ios, watchkit

I want to make the background image transparent so that the above text can be visible on it.
But in WatchKit, we can only set the Group as a background image and if we make the group alpha less so whole UI lets transparent.

I want something like Pandora app,like the background image shown transparent so that the above text is proper visible.:

[image]

Please help.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, if you fade the `WKInterfaceGroup`, everything within that group also fades. The same thing happens with any container. As a result, the only way to achieve this with the current version of WatchKit is to pre-process the image yourself before sending it to the Watch.

Update: I now wonder if you could set the full color image as the background of a full-screen group, then set the background color of another group to a semi-transparent black.

I tried the group-on-top-of-group technique, and while you can use it to darken a full-color image, there's no way to apply the slight blurring effect without pre-processing the image. Here is the quick result with a black, semi-transparent gradient as the background of the second group:

[image]

Comment: What color you set for semi transparent black.

Comment: It wasn't a color. I created a quick black, semi-transparent gradient image in Photoshop and used it as the background of the second group.